# DebugView not showing debug output from VB.NET program

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

I am using Debug.WriteLine() in a VB.NET program.  I can see the debug statements in Visual Studio's "Output" window, but not in DebugView.

I even tried the following:

[Using DebugView with .NET tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/05/20/using-debugview-to-catch-debug-output-of-net-program.aspx)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .Net Framework 4.0 or newer then this is By Design.  When debugging an application the output of `Debug.WriteLine` will go to the debugger but not to the DebugView application.

This changed in 4.0 because of some architeture details of the Visual Studio debugger.  It turned into a true native debugger and Debug View can't intercept messages over a native debugger